# Flask URL Display

Tags: python, url, flask

I have a custom url that looks like

```
@app.route('/user/<user_name>/<param>')
def show_param(user_name, param):
    #do something
```

The page displays fine and is working well but `param` can have spaces, etc, in it, and I'd rather not show those. What I'd like to do is change the visual display of `param` before it's shown to users. How do I get access to that?

Comment: What do you mean by "change the visual display of param before it's shown to users"? eg: the user's address bar or something?

Comment: Not sure what you mean ? Are you saying that the URL allows spaces ?

Comment: If you want to limit what type of values `param` will match you need to specify a converter. Flask / Werkzeug come with converters for string (everything but a `/`, the default), `int` and `float`. You'll have to create a custom converter if you something else.

Comment: To be clear, I just want to change the url bar from showing something like /user/myname/foo%20bar to /user/myname/foo-bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could tweak the URL to suit your taste and then redirect to that.

```
@app.route('/user/<user_name>/<param>')
def show_param(user_name, param):
    if ' ' in param:
        param = param.replace(' ', '-')
        return redirect(url_for('show_param'), user_name=user_name, param=param)
```

Comment: You should use `url_for()` to generate the redirect URL.